# Two names for a C# static class

Tags: c#, static-classes

It's extremely lazy, but I'm wondering if it's possible to have two names point to the same static class in essence.

I have a long and descriptive static class name `BusinessLogicServiceUtility` (as example) and it's looking rather long-winded in code.

I'd love to use `BLSU` as an alternative, so I tried extending the long class with my short class name:

```
public static class BLSU : BusinessLogicServiceUtility
{
}
```

Which probably looks noob but as it turns out, it doesn't work.

It looks as though I could wrap each method in the long class with a method inside the short class, but there's a **lot** of methods, which makes maintaining it a pain and circumvents the whole laziness goal.

Is there a way of assigning two names to one static class, or some other method simply "extending" a static class?

Comment: Having spent a lot of time working on legacy code, I would avoid the "lazy" road (as you put it). It doesn't take long before the code base becomes incoherent.  Some employers may see this as a risk to the company - you will be the only one with the magic decoder ring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an alias for a type:

```
using BLSU = Your.Namespace.BusinessLogicServiceUtility;
```

Accessing members of type:

```
BLSU.SomeStaticMethod();
```

---

With C# 6 you can even go further - access static members of a type *without* having to qualify type name at all:

```
using static Your.Namespace.BusinessLogicServiceUtility;
```

Accessing members of type:

```
SomeStaticMethod();
```

Further reading: [using Directive (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you can use `using static` that will allow you to use the methods without prefixing them with the class at all:

at the top of the file :

```
using static BusinessLogicServiceUtility;
```

and say you have a method `public static DoLogicThings()` in your static class, you can access it directly now:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
     DoLogicThings();
}
```

this was added in C#6.